# Arrange Excel Cell Row Data under relevant columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large file of excel data where row data is not present under the relevant columns.

```
         Name      City       School            College         Address
        City:abc  Name:abc    College:abc   Address:abc     School: abc
        City:abc  College:abc Name:abc      School: abc     Address:abc
```

I have hundreds of such rows.
What I want is something like this :

```
Name        City        School       College            Address
Name:abc    City:abc    School:abc   College:abc        Address:abc
Name:abc    City:abc    School:abc   College:abc        Address:abc
```

I have identifiers before semicolon (:) in cell, but can't seem to match it to the column.

I have tried `MATCH()` Function for identifiers like School etc. but it can't work because Exact Match (Third field of MATCH() Function) won't work, other options can cause errors. Also `Filter()` doesn't seem to work either.
Kindly help me with an approach that can automate this. Can a formula be made for this or VBA code can work ? 
I don't want to do so much manual work.

THANKS

**EDIT**

ANSWER:

Thanks Karpak for the answer. I just came up with the following solution before visiting your post.

For others, who are facing a similar problem, try this:

```
=INDEX(range, MATCH("SearcItem"&"*",Range,0), 1)
```

This will return the value of the cell after matching it up.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Is the first screen shot, 5 columns or 1?

Comment: If the screen shot is multiple columns, you could use, an array formula, like `=MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(A1,$A$2:$E$2),0),COLUMN($A$2:$E$2))` where A1="Name" and A:E is the data as in the below screen shot, that gives the column index of the data, wildcards could also be used :)

Comment: Thanks alot Nathan for the valuable input . Really appreciate it. A different perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match with wildcard should work. Try with

```
=MATCH("Name:*",1:1,0)
=MATCH("College:*",1:1,0)
=MATCH("Address:*",1:1,0)
=MATCH("City:*",1:1,0)
=MATCH("School:*",1:1,0)
```

The above works for row 1. If you want to make it for row two replace 1:1 with 2:2 or if you want a specific cells, use A2:E2 etc.